# Getting ?? holoview chord hovertool tooltip

Tags: jupyter-notebook, bokeh, holoviews, chord-diagram

I'm trying to customize the hover of holoview chord diagram. Below is the sample code that I'm using. I don't know where I'm making mistake, whenever I hover over the nodes I get question marks only on the tooltip.

```
source_data = [{"from": "Cronje", "to": "Lord Kitchener", "value": 1}, {"from": "Cronje", "to": "Lord Selborne", "value": 1}, {"from": "Cronje", "to": "George Godfrey", "value": 1}]

import pandas as pd
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts, dim
import numpy as np
hv.extension('bokeh')
hv.output(size=300)

df_json = pd.DataFrame(source_data)
df_links = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['source', 'target', 'value'])
df_links['source'] = df_json['from'].values.tolist()
df_links['target'] = df_json['to'].values.tolist()
df_links['value'] = df_json['value'].values.tolist()
chord = hv.Chord(df_links)
tooltips = [
    ('Source', '@source'),
    ('Target', '@target'),
    ('Value', '@value')
]
from bokeh.models import HoverTool
hover = HoverTool(tooltips=tooltips)
chord.opts(tools=[hover],
    node_color=dim('index').str(), edge_color=dim('source').str(), label_index='index', 
    cmap='Category20', edge_cmap='Category20', width=500, height=500)
```

After the plot, when I hover I get a question mark on nodes.
Could you please help!